# How to express out $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is given that $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=\frac1 {x} + \frac1 {y}$. How to express out $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$? I wonder is it possible to do so? Could you give any hints?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$ and $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x+y}{xy}$. Therefore you can write your equations in terms of $A=x+y$ and $B=xy$. If you know $A$ and $B$ in terms of $u,v$, then $x,y$ are the solutions of $X^2-AX+B=0$.

Comment: There are more than one. The simplest is $$\left(x=\frac{1+\sqrt{u v^2+1}+\sqrt{u v^2-2 \sqrt{u v^2+1}-2}}{2 v},\\y=\frac{1+\sqrt{u v^2+1}-\sqrt{u v^2-2 \sqrt{u v^2+1}-2}}{2 v}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach: solve the second equation for $y$ to get:
$$ y = \frac{1}{v-1/x} = \frac{x}{xv-1}.$$
Put the result into the first equation:
$$ u = x^2 + \left(\frac{x}{xv-1}\right)^2 $$
and solve for $x$. Once you know what $x$ is in terms of $u$ and $v$, you can then put that in the second equation and solve for $y$ as well.